# XMLHttpRequest does not work on 32-bit machine, IE10 in IE8 standards document mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, 32bit-64bit, x-ua-compatible

Wondering if anyone has hit this bizarre IE / javascript error before.

On a 32-bit machine using IE10 in IE8 standards document mode, javascript returns a TypeError when trying to create a new XMLHttpRequest object. This is an issue since one of our pages forces IE8 standards via an X-UA-Compatible IE=8 meta tag (a requirement of the page).

**new window.XMLHttpRequest();**
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action

This exact same line of code from a 64-bit machine (IE10 in IE8 standards) works just fine.


**32-bit IE10 IE8 standards**
[image: 32-bit IE10 IE8 standards]

**64-bit IE10 IE8 standards**
[image: 64-bit IE10 IE8 standards]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue using angularjs version 1.2.9. Turns out, angular doesn't do the best job detecting the availability of window.XMLHttpRequest(). jQuery is a little more thorough in their approach.

angularjs 1.2.9

```
function createXhr(method) {
   // IE8 doesn't support PATCH method, but the ActiveX object does
   /* global ActiveXObject */
   return (msie <= 8 && lowercase(method) === 'patch')
      ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      : new window.XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

jQuery 1.10.2

```
// Functions to create xhrs
function createStandardXHR() {
    try {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
}

function createActiveXHR() {
    try {
        return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch( e ) {}
}

// Create the request object
// (This is still attached to ajaxSettings for backward compatibility)
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = window.ActiveXObject ?
    /* Microsoft failed to properly
    * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
    * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
    * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
    * we need a fallback.
    */
    function() {
        return !this.isLocal && createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
    } :
    // For all other browsers, use the standard XMLHttpRequest object
    createStandardXHR;

// Determine support properties
xhrSupported = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
```

For me, the fix was to add an additional condition that checks for IE8 document mode to angular's createXhr method:

```
function createXhr(method) {
   // IE8 doesn't support PATCH method, but the ActiveX object does
   /* global ActiveXObject */
   return ((msie <= 8 && lowercase(method) === 'patch') ||
        (msie >= 8 && document.documentMode == 8))
      ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      : new window.XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

The alternative would be to implement jQuery's approach which looks to see if ActiveXObject is available. If it is then tries to create a standard XMLHttpRequest, if that fails it falls back on the ActiveX alternative.